# Wordpress Forms

Tags: php, wordpress

I was wondering if it is at all possible to write a php file that will take a form submission from an external server and add the submission to wordpress as a blog post. The file should return a post->ID. Thanks

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post might help you

Comment: An iframe could be a solution too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the form processed on the remote server, you can remotely add the submission to WordPress via XMLRPC.

An example as follows:

```
<?php

class XMLRPClientWordPress
{

    var $XMLRPCURL = "";
    var $UserName  = "";
    var $PassWord = "";

    // constructor
    public function __construct($xmlrpcurl, $username, $password) 
    {
        $this->XMLRPCURL = $xmlrpcurl;
        $this->UserName  = $username;
        $this->PassWord = $password;

    }
    function send_request($requestname, $params) 
    {
        $request = xmlrpc_encode_request($requestname, $params);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->XMLRPCURL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
        $results = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $results;
    }

    function create_post($title,$body,$category,$keywords='',$encoding='UTF-8')
    {
        $title = htmlentities($title,ENT_NOQUOTES,$encoding);
        $keywords = htmlentities($keywords,ENT_NOQUOTES,$encoding);

        $content = array(
            'title'=>$title,
            'description'=>$body,
            'mt_allow_comments'=>0,  // 1 to allow comments
            'mt_allow_pings'=>0,  // 1 to allow trackbacks
            'post_type'=>'post',
            'mt_keywords'=>$keywords,
            'categories'=>array($category)
        );
        $params = array(0,$this->UserName,$this->PassWord,$content,true);

        return $this->send_request('metaWeblog.newPost',$params);

    }

    function create_page($title,$body,$encoding='UTF-8')
    {
        $title = htmlentities($title,ENT_NOQUOTES,$encoding);

        $content = array(
            'title'=>$title,
            'description'=>$body
        );
        $params = array(0,$this->UserName,$this->PassWord,$content,true);

        return $this->send_request('wp.newPage',$params);
    }

    function display_authors()
    {
        $params = array(0,$this->UserName,$this->PassWord);
        return $this->send_request('wp.getAuthors',$params);
    }

    function sayHello()
    {
        $params = array();
        return $this->send_request('demo.sayHello',$params);
    }

}

if(trim($_POST['subject'])=='' || trim($_POST['content'])==''){
    die('All fields are required.');
}

$xmlrpc = new XMLRPClientWordPress("http://yoursite.com/xmlrpc.php" , "username" , "password");

$xmlrpc->create_post( mb_convert_encoding(stripslashes($_POST['subject']), 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), mb_convert_encoding(htmlentities(stripslashes($_POST['content']), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), 1);

echo 'Post successful!';

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this file, however how do I return a post->ID?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, $xmlrpc->create_post() should return with something containing the post ID. Try var_dump()ing it.